# Accessing other row value in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have dataset containing number of rows.
I am using this dataset in SSRS 2008

While displaying the records I need to access value from particular row. 
For Example

Dataset

```
    Item  column1   column2  column3

    abc      20        20      20
    cbd      30        30      30
    xyz      40        40      40
    yrk      50        50      50
```

While displaying the 6th record in row
I need to access column1 value where Item is 'cbd'

how can I do that?

Could you please help?

Thanks,
Chetan

Comment: It sounds like you should update you SQL statement to pull the data as-needed for the report. It's always more difficult to create and maintain reports that include logic on the data - it's much easier in the query.

Comment: Thank You.. Isn't there any simpler way? Cant we use c#code in SSRS 2008 like we can to do in SSIS

Answer (score 0):

You can use =ReportItems!Textbox64.Value

here textbox64 refers to the source value